# What do @mock.patch decorators do in Python when there are more than the number of parameters of the decorated method/function?

Tags: python, mocking, decorator

For example:

```
@patch('my.project.trading.getEnrichedTradeData', lambda: TEST_TRADE_DATA)
@patch('my.project.subledger.getSubledgerData', getTestSubledgerData)
@patch('my.project.metadata.getSubledgerCodes', return_value=TEST_CODES)
@patch('my.project.reports.storeReport')
def test(self, storeReport):
    buildReport()
    storeReport.assert_called_with(EXPECTED_REPORT)
```

```
def buildReport():
    trades = getEnrichedTradeData()
    subledger = getSubledgerData()
    codes = getSubledgerCodes()
    report = Report(trades, subledger, codes)
    storeReport(report)
```

I thought that @patch passes its return value as an argument, so that's what will happen with the bottom-most decorator. What about the other 3?
Disclaimer: Fairly green in python speak. Proficient in Java and C++. Please be as detailed as possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from the documentation of [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

> If `new` is omitted, then the target is replaced with an `AsyncMock` if
>   the patched object is an async function or a `MagicMock` otherwise. If
>   `patch()` is used as a decorator and new is omitted, the created mock is
>   passed in as an extra argument to the decorated function.

Since in your case, all of the 3 top `patch` decorators are called with the `new` argument, the 3 target objects would simply be replaced with the objects from the `new` argument, and the bottom `patch` decorator, without a `new` argument, would replace the target object with a `MagicMock` instance and pass it in as the extra argument `storeReport` to your `test` function.

Comment: Do you mean that I would have to change the function signature or that the decorators end up adding/inserting extra parameters? I see working code that doesn't add arguments and works with more decorators than number of arguments like the example I sent.

Comment: My bad. I totally forgot that no extra arguments would be passed in if the `new` argument is specified for the `patch` decorator. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Got it now... Basically @patch only passes the created mock object as an argument if `new` is omitted. Otherwise, it simply patches `target` with `new`. Thank you!

Comment: Do we know how the function distinguishes between extra arguments, vs. matching the existing arguments? For instance, how does pytest know that `@patch('my.project.metadata.getSubledgerCodes', return_value=TEST_CODES)` does not map to `storeReport`?